# Should an address be restricted from sending unlimited XLM to itself?

Tags: transactions, stellar-core, network

Hello Stellar Community,

While testing our wallets yesterday we noticed that an address is able to 'send' itself more XLM than the current total supply limit, ex: 105 Billion XLM. Although the net result is simply paying a transaction fee as the account is debited/credited at the same time, the transaction does appear on explorers.

Reference Address:
GA2HB3PRIKRDHJPJE54MLC5MCSRSHUPIKF2XIAOD4UIXQWGTWTIPHFB7

https://stellar.expert/explorer/public/account/GA2HB3PRIKRDHJPJE54MLC5MCSRSHUPIKF2XIAOD4UIXQWGTWTIPHFB7

See the above transaction, showing 105 Billion XLM.
Although the impact is low as the user is not creating anything new.. should this be allowed as it could potentially mislead services that track network statistics (average transaction size etc). What are your thoughts?

Cheers,
Jon

Comment: Seems to be a bug. Great you fond this. :)

Answer (score 4):

I'd said that such behavior is rather a bug. Confirmed on both, public and test networks.

Definitely should be reported [here](https://github.com/stellar/stellar-core/issues).

Comment: Reported :) https://github.com/stellar/stellar-core/issues/1642#issuecomment-377969184